# elasticsearch 6 alternative to groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch

In version 6, the scripts are no longer available!

Does anyone know how to implement a script (function_score with match_phrase_prefix) with distance levenshtein in elasticsearch 6?

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "name": {
                        "query": "product name",
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                }
            },
    (...)
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "function_score": {
                                "query": {
                                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "query": "product",
                                            "boost": 0,
                                            "slop": 2
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "functions": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "script": {
                                                "lang": "groovy",
                                                "inline": "def termInfo = [];  termInfo = _index['name'].get('product',_POSITIONS | _OFFSETS ); c = _source.name.size(); sf = -1; for(pos in termInfo){sf = pos.startOffset; ;break;}; if(sf<0 || c < 1 ){return _score;}; score = _score + (c - sf);  score = score.div(c) * 400; return score;"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "function_score": {
                                "query": {
                                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "query": "name",
                                            "boost": 0,
                                            "slop": 2
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "functions": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "script": {
                                                "lang": "groovy",
                                                "inline": "def termInfo = [];  termInfo = _index['name'].get('name',_POSITIONS | _OFFSETS ); c = _source.name.size(); sf = -1; for(pos in termInfo){sf = pos.startOffset; ;break;}; if(sf<0 || c < 1 ){return _score;}; score = _score + (c - sf);  score = score.div(c) * 200; return score;"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I want to make a script for Elastic search 6 in which the terms with the highest correspondence appear better classified.

The ideal will be to implement the levenshtein distance. Does anyone know how to implement? How can I implement in Elasticsearch 6?

query for "product name":

```
name1 = abcd cool more more product name
name2 = cool more cool product name abcd cool more more
name3 = product abcd name cool more more
name4 = product abcd cool name more more
name5 = product name cool abcd cool more more
```

result of search:

```
name5 = **product name** cool abcd cool more more
name2 = cool more cool product name abcd cool more more
name3 = **product** abcd **name** cool more more
name1 = abcd cool more more **product name**
name4 = **product** abcd cool name more more
```

In the above script, the closer the search phrase is to the beginning of the sentence the more punctuation it will get.

Thank you
Thanks

Comment: Try providing examples of code you have tried, to help people help you :) Welcome to SO!

Comment: hello. thansk. Any idea?